# Jquery: programmatically trigger click event on mega-dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to programmatically trigger a click event on a mega-dropdown when a button is clicked. I have tried the following but did not work.

MEGA-DROPDOWN HTML CODE

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown mega-dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="ti-layers-alt"></i>

    <div class="notify"> <span class="heartbit"></span> <span class="point"></span> </div>

  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu animated bounceInDown">
    <ul class="mega-dropdown-menu row">

      <li class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">

        <center>
          <h2>Message Subject</h2>
        </center>
        <center>
          <h4>Message Body</h4>
        </center>

      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

```
<button type="button" onclick="showMegaDropDown()" >Show Mega Dropdown</button>
```

JavaScript Code

```
showMegaDropDown(){
  $(".mega-dropdown").trigger('click');
  return;
}
```

Comment: please check console log

Comment: share the style also

Comment: jQuery must come first before bootstrap js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the event object in html

```
<button type="button" onclick="showMegaDropDown(event)">Show Mega Dropdown</button>
```

change the script:

```
function showMegaDropDown(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
        }
```

order of cdn:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please how do i check if the drop-down is already opened so i don't toggle it.  I only want to toggle it when it is closed.

Comment: if ($('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-menu').is(":hidden")) {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
  }

Answer (score 0):

add function keyword in front of your function name

```
function showMegaDropDown() {
   $(".mega-dropdown").trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the `li` tag is not what you want to click.  Try clicking the `a` tag instead...

```
function showMegaDropDown(){
  $(".mega-dropdown a").trigger('click');
  return false;
}
```